# App crash when I press the button to sum two values

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext

My app crash when I try to press the button to sum the edittext and I don't know how to fix because I can't see the app logs.
How I check my logs ?

My code (`MainActivity.kt`):

```
package com.example.paymentothetrip

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var kmtotal = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ikmtotal)
        var ilitro = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ilitro)
        var ikmforlit = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ikmforlit)
        val btncalcular: TextView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btncalcular)

        btncalcular.setOnClickListener{
            calcular(kmtotal, ikmforlit, ilitro, )
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun calcular(kmtotal: EditText, ikmforlit: EditText, ilitro: EditText) {

        val txtresult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtresult)
        var result: Double = (kmtotal.text.toString().toDouble() / ikmforlit.text.toString().toDouble()) * ilitro.toString().toDouble()

        txtresult.text = "R$ $result"

    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
2022-02-26 21:16:10.655 19167-19167/com.example.paymentothetrip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.paymentothetrip, PID: 19167
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{28c5fa0 VFED..CL. ........ 0,745-1080,883 #7f0a01df app:id/ilitro aid=1073741825}"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.example.paymentothetrip.MainActivity.calcular(MainActivity.kt:32)
        at com.example.paymentothetrip.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at com.example.paymentothetrip.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$x4PiI7hxLHE9UUw2OiqZu2i-kE4(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.paymentothetrip.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:8)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2022-02-26 21:16:10.670 19167-19167/com.example.paymentothetrip I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19167 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You can see the logs in the ``Logcat`` tab: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat Make sure you've got your device/emulator selected, and you're not filtering out your messages. If it's a physical device, check you've turned on USB Debugging.

Comment: We need the error log to know why your app is crashing, but at a guess, one of your ``EditText``s has a string that can't be parsed as a ``Double``. That or ``txtResult`` is null because ``R.id.txtresult`` doesn't exist in your layout (or it's not a ``TextView``). You're passing in an ``EditText`` called ``result`` that you're not using, are you supposed to set the value on that instead?

Comment: @cactustictacs i remove my the variable and paramets result but didnt solve my problem i put my new log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Just explaining how you can track the bug down - the fix is at the bottom)*

Your error log says this is the cause of the crash:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{28c5fa0 VFED..CL. ........ 0,745-1080,883 #7f0a01df app:id/ilitro aid=1073741825}"
```

A `NumberFormatException` is usually caused when you try to convert some text into a number, but you can't - it's not formatted like a recognisable number. You're trying to parse `String`s as `Double`s here, so there's a good chance a string contains text that can't be read as a valid `Double`.

The error tells you the input string that's causing it:

```
"androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{28c5fa0 VFED..CL. ........ 0,745-1080,883 #7f0a01df app:id/ilitro aid=1073741825}"
```

That's what you're calling `toDouble()` on. It's obviously wrong, right? You're expecting something like `1.234` or whatever you entered. That text is a reference to an `AppCompatEditText` object, the widget itself. Something's gone wrong with getting the text content from that widget.

So let's look at your code where you read the text from those `EditText`s, and try to parse them as `Double`s:

```
var result: Double = (kmtotal.text.toString().toDouble() / ikmforlit.text.toString().toDouble())
    * ilitro.toString().toDouble()
```

You see which one of those is different? For the first two, you're accessing `kmtotal.text` and `ikmforlit.text` and calling `toString` on that, to get the `text` contents as a string. But for the last one, you're not accessing its `text` - you're calling `toString()` on the `EditText`itself. That's why you're getting that description of the object in the error message - that's the string you're trying to parse

---

So the solution is you need to change it to `ilitro.text.toString()` instead of `ilitro.toString()`. I just wanted to explain why it's happening, and how you can use the error log to track issues down. It tells you where the problem is too:

```
at com.example.paymentothetrip.MainActivity.calcular(MainActivity.kt:32)
```

that's the first line of the stacktrace that's in *your* code, that's the last thing your code did before the error happened (line 32 of `MainActivity`). That's a good place to start looking for bugs!